# TextView to open PDF File, Android Studio

Tags: android

The scenario as the following, after the user login, the application returns he/she visiting numbers for example:
123
150
I preview the values on Text View, how I can make it clickable? and open PDF file like when user click on 150 open the PDF file that located on server 150.PDF????

Comment: Please add code samples and a better description of what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a way to test this at this exact moment, but why not just hyperlink the TextView?

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.myserver.com/123.pdf'> 123 </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

I'm not 100% sure, but clicking it should just prompt the user for which PDF viewer they want and open that pdf.